# How can I produce a full length fade In menu from a small 45x45px image?

Tags: html, css, image, drop-down-menu, hover

I am trying to have a full length (Width: 100%) fade In menu appear when one hovers over a small 45px x 45px image? 
I have tried different ways of getting the menu at 100% width once I hover but no luck. The code below seems to make the most sense to me in terms of steps but it still does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you,
Edwin

```css
.nav {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 45px;
}

.menu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #aaaaaa;
 background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
 background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 transition-delay: 5s;
}

.nav:hover .menu {
 display: block;
 animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
 from {opacity: 0;}
 to   {opacity: 3;}
}

li {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 75px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px #3fddff;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <img src="down-arrow.png" height="45px" width="45px" alt="Down Arrow" class="down">
   <ul class="menu">
    <a href="#"><li>Example1</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Example2</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Example3</li></a>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML in your menu was wrong. `li` should be the direct descendent of `ul`. Removing `absolute` positioning from the nav `.menu` allows it to take up space on the page so that your `.nav:hover .menu` will continue to show `.menu` when you mouse between the image and the menu. Also removed the width from `.nav` so that the `.menu` links can expand the width of the page.

```css
.nav {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

.menu {
 display: none;
 background-color: #aaaaaa;
 background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
 background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 transition-delay: 5s;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav:hover .menu {
 display: block;
 animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
 from {opacity: 0;}
 to   {opacity: 3;}
}

li {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 75px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px #3fddff;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <img src="down-arrow.png" height="45px" width="45px" alt="Down Arrow" class="down">
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Example1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Example1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Example1</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "width:100%" do you mean the whole viewport, or just the whole width of the container element?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that when I hover over the image the menu will fade in. The problem I have is that if I place the mouse over any area parallel to the image the menu will fade in and I only want it to fade in when I hover over the image only.

Comment: Use the code below provided by Michael Coker, but add (width: 45px; height: 45px;) to your .nav element and it should work the way you want it to. Your nav is extending all the way across the page, and you've set your hover to the nav element instead of the image.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code below as per Michael Coker however now when I hover over the image the menu fades In, in the actual width of the image (width: 45px) I want it to come out the full width of the screen. thanks again.

Comment: YES!!!  Thank you GRRRilla Ninja!!  This exactly it. My apologies if I didn't describe what I needed better.